# Does multiple assignment have order?

Tags: go

I know golang supports multiple assignment, for instance,

```
a, b = c, d
```

I want to know if the assignment following the left->right order? For instance, if I play with trees:

```
parent, child = child, child.child
```

Does it guarantee both parent and child are assigned one level deeper in the tree?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. From the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of index expressions and pointer indirections (including implicit pointer indirections in selectors) on the left and the expressions on the right are all evaluated in the usual order. Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.

So in your example, `child` and `child.child` will be evaluated first, then assigned to `parent` and `child` respectively.

Comment: That's quite interesting. But when i try to swap a value using multiple assignment here https://play.golang.org/p/76Q8OSGfr4, it just works and looks like go copy the value into another location during operation.

Comment: @Kebeng: Yes, implicit in the quoted text above is that the values of the evaluated right-side expressions are stored temporarily until they are assigned to the left-side variables.